# Is there a way to find the 0th index a variable amount of times?

Tags: python, arrays

I don't really have a good reason for needing to know this, but is it possible to find the 0th index a certain amount of times? Say like you have this piece of code

```
ar = [[[["a"]]]]
print(ar[0][0][0][0])
```

but instead of the 4 `[0][0][0][0]` you can just do like `ar([0]*4)`. Anyway, thanks for the help.

Comment: What happened when you tried writing code to solve the problem?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel the OP is actually asking if Python has a built-in way for doing this without implementing it himself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do sounds weird because you will rarely run into a situation where you have an unknown nesting structure. That said, a loop is the first thing you should think of when you encounter a problem of the type "do X a bunch of times".

For example, you could set `ar` to the zeroth element of `ar` as long as `ar` is an instance of type `list` and is also not empty.

```
ar = [[[["a"]]]]
while isinstance(ar, list) and len(ar) > 0:
    ar = ar[0]

print(ar) # output: a
```

Note: `len(ar) > 0` is just for clarity if you're a beginner. Empty lists are falsey, so you could have also just done `while isinstance(ar, list) and ar:`

You could also specify how many times you can drill down and the index to which you want to drill down:

```
def drill_down(arg, index, count):
    for i in range(count):
        if isinstance(arg, list) and len(arg) > index:
            arg = arg[index]
    return arg

ar = [[[["a"]]]]
result = drill_down(ar)
print(result) # Output: a
```

Or, you could use a recursive function, which can be made to behave similar to a loop:

```
def drill_down(arg, index, count):
    if isinstance(arg, list) and len(arg) > index and count > 0:
        return drill_down(arg[index], index, count - 1)
    return arg

ar = [[[["a"]]]]
result = drill_down(ar)
print(result) # Output: a
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `functools` and `itertools` to define a function that repeatedly indexes into the `ith` element of an array `count` times :)

```py
import functools
import itertools

find_nth_elem = lambda n, arr: arr[n]

def repeated_index(arr, i, count):
    """Index into `i`th element of `arr` a total of `count` times."""

    # get _an iterator of_ `count` copies of the same function, lazy eval
    index_calls = itertools.repeat(functools.partial(find_nth_elem, i), count)

    # f(f(f(...f(arr)...))), where f(x) = get nth element of x.
    return functools.reduce(lambda acc, f: f(acc), index_calls, arr)

arr = [[[["a"]]]]
print(repeated_index(arr, 0, 4))
```